# How to keep rest api calls in different file in react js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to react js and have been building something which works absolutely fine. But as of now the api calls to be made are defined inside respective components. So if any changes to be made to the ip or endpoint, i need to make changes at every place. How can i separate all the api calls in one file and perform the operation on result in respective component file.

Below is an example :

```
import axios from "axios";

function get_all_user(){
axios({
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/users/",
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      
}

function get_single_user(userid){

axios({
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/users/"+userid,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      
}
```

in every component i have api calls to make. all these api calls needs to be at one place. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just move whole of this code into another component and add word `export` before function definition like:

```
export function get_all_user(){
  // rest of code
}
```

and then you just have to import that in your components

```
import { get_all_user } from './path/to/file/'
```

so you can use them in multiple files by:

```
get_all_user()
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-q0z7d?file=/index.js) is an example, it `text.js` file you have exported function, in `index.js` file you just use it

Comment: yes i have tried it, but getting this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error.

Comment: @liquiddeath because you need return data and then only you can use then in another file, return Promise.resolve(response.data)

Comment: @SudarshanRai how to do that? can you please show me with an example. this is my first project with react js

Comment: @liquiddeath you can see my answer i have done easier method , you can try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios [instance method](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults) , you stetup your Api config in one file then import and use

/api.js

```
import axios from "axios";
export const axiosRequest = axios.create({
  baseUrl: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
});
```

/app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { axiosRequest } from './api';
export default function App() {

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    axiosRequest.get('/todos/1')
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .catch(err=>console.log(res))
  },[])
  
  return <>axios</>
}
```

here is working code example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wind-cisn7?file=/src/api.js:0-125)

Comment: i have kept baseurl as http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/. and did as you mentioned above. but the request made doesn't have app included in the request. it looks like http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/